# Android - does onPostResume get called after fragment is resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I cant seem to find this answer using search engine but in the case of  an activity hosting a fragment, when the activities onPostResume method is called, i am assuming that any attached fragments onResume methods will already have been called. who can confirm ?

Comment: who can confirm ? LOGS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Native `Activity`

```
final void performResume() {
    ...
    mInstrumentation.callActivityOnResume(this);
    ...
    mFragments.dispatchResume();
    mFragments.execPendingActions();

    onPostResume();
    ...
}
```

## Support `FragmentActivity`

```
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    ...
    onResumeFragments();
    mFragments.execPendingActions();
}
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    mFragments.dispatchResume();
}
```

So here it depends on whether you do stuff with fragments before or after calling `super.onPostResume()` in your `@Override`.

Answer (score 4):

turns out i had automatic build turned off in eclipse thats why when i tested it myself i was getting strange results.  But for those wondering...

1. first an activity resumes
2. then a fragment resumes
3. lastly the host activites onPostResume is called.

so fragments are resumed within the activities onResume method.  But that is not guaranteed. The better approach would be to override onResumeFragment. This call back ensures the fragments are resumed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `Fragment` was added by the `ViewPager`.
Here is the Log:

Activity: onResume
Activity: onResumeFragments
Activity: onPostResume
Fragment: onResume